# StackView Not Aligning To The Left Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, stackview

My StackView that I am making programmatically is looking like this:

*Two Subviews:*

[image]

*Three Subviews:*

[image]

*Four Subviews:*

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
    cameraButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "blueCamera"), for: .normal)
    cameraButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    cameraButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0).isActive = true
    calenderButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "calender"), for: .normal)
    calenderButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(calanderTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    calenderButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0).isActive = true

    stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollViewHeight)
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    stackView.alignment = .fill // .leading .firstBaseline .center .trailing .lastBaseline
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing // .fillEqually .fillProportionally .equalSpacing .equalCentering
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(calenderButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(cameraButton)
    stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.161, green: 0.165, blue: 0.188, alpha: 1.00)
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
```

**What is the problem:**
The StackView is not aligning the subviews to the left.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I want all the subviews aligned to the left, I tried to do this with `stackView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight`, but that didn't seem to achieve much.

Comment: try stackView.alignment = .leading

Comment: @Alexander Nope.

Comment: take away semanticContentAttribute?

Comment: you need to put 4 views inside stack view with clear color and then add button inside those views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set:

```swift
    stackView.alignment = .leading
```

And remove This:

```swift
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
```

Your code then will be like:

```swift
    cameraButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "blueCamera"), for: .normal)
    cameraButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    cameraButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0).isActive = true
    calenderButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "calender"), for: .normal)
    calenderButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(calanderTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    calenderButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0).isActive = true

    stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.size.width, height: scrollViewHeight)
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.alignment = .leading    
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(calenderButton)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(cameraButton)
    stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.161, green: 0.165, blue: 0.188, alpha: 1.00)
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using transparent `UIView` with dynamic width. So each image view will have width constraint except this `UIView`. Also set `stackView.alignment` and `stackView..distribution` properties to `.fill`.

Using this you can show/hide imageViews with consistent left alignment.

Here is quick setup using storyboard. As you can see all images have width set to 60 except last `UIView` names "Blue Dynamic Width View". 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Couple options...

1) Constrain stack view Leading and Bottom, but not Trailing; Constrain width and height of first subview; Constrain additional subviews equal width and height to first subview; give stack view desired spacing.

2) Constrain stack view Leading, Trailing and Bottom; Constrain width and height of first subview; Constrain additional subviews equal width and height to first subview; give stack Distribution: Equal Spacing; add extra clear subviews to add up to 4 total subviews.

3) Same constraints as 2, but add 4 clear subviews, then add buttons as subviews of those subviews.